# Message: Undefined index: signed_request facebook registration plugin

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, facebook-apps, facebook-authentication

I am trying to use facebook registration plugin with following code

```
<?php
   define('FACEBOOK_APP_ID', 'your_app_id');
   define('FACEBOOK_SECRET', 'your_app_secret');

   function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
     list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

     // decode the data
     $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
     $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

     if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
       error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
       return null;
     }

     // check sig
     $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
     if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
       error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
       return null;
     }

     return $data;
   }

   function base64_url_decode($input) {
       return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
   }

   if ($_REQUEST) {
     echo '<p>signed_request contents:</p>';
     $response = parse_signed_request($_REQUEST['signed_request'], 
                               FACEBOOK_SECRET);
     echo '<pre>';
     print_r($response);
     echo '</pre>';
   } else {
     echo '$_REQUEST is empty';
   }
   ?>
```

However, I got this error message Message: Undefined index: signed_request and I looked into $_REQUEST and I found only $_REQUEST['code'] rather than $_REQUEST['signed_request'],

ref : facebookRegister/?code=AQBtVIDd-5MOklcFX0mRS_Pt1ht8svD6Soh_kNKiD8XG1QVPet6kVdVby7C8pDe1WwxBFIcqWDPVAEN1f4NBo_ZB5U1_19EV3bnYIGWv16Nok0IVWEXL4MYDB1p1VU2iEFq9NnH2TzFXXZQzEJWG5Jw9sTKAEK6GPpKdESaNiAkYBTZRl0qMv97O8HI1-Yu0PfI#*=*

Anybody has idea whats wrong and highly appreciate for reply

Thank you very much